# What are the recommended ways to handle references to embedded documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, reference

I'm new to MongoDB.  Here's my problem: a user can have multiple avatars, but one and only one is active.  Here's what a user document looks like for the moment:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("515c99f7e4d8094a87e13757"),
  "avatars": [{
    "url": "http://example.com/img/photo1.jpg",
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50,
  }, {
    "active": true,
    "url": "http://example.com/img/photo2.jpg",
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50,
  }]
}
```

This solution is simple enough, but there are a few things I don't like:

1. changing the active avatar means updating two embedded documents
2. I'm not sure it will behave nicely in case of concurrent access (read_avatar+change_active_avatar or change_active+change_active) (will it?)
3. looking for the active avatar requires a sequential search

Another solution would be this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("515c99f7e4d8094a87e13757"),
  "active_avatar_id": 2,
  "avatars": [{
    "_id": 1,
    "url": "http://example.com/img/photo1.jpg",
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50,
  }, {
    "_id": 2,
    "url": "http://example.com/img/photo2.jpg",
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50,
  }]
}
```

This fixes problems 1&2, but not problem 3.  And it adds an extra `_id` field in every embedded document.  Plus when I insert a new avatar I now need to know what's the next `_id` to use (unless I use an objectId, but then it's a 12 bytes id for just a few hundred avatars (max).

So yet another solution could be this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("515c99f7e4d8094a87e13757"),
  "active_avatar": {
    "url": "http://example.com/img/photo2.jpg",
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50,
  },
  "extra_avatars": [{
    "url": "http://example.com/img/photo1.jpg",
    "width": 50,
    "height": 50,
  }]
}
```

Not much better than the first solution (it just fixes problem #3, that's it, and it's uglier).

All these solutions work, but I'm looking for "the right way" to do it.  Any ideas?  And what if I allow users to have multiple active avatars (whatever that would mean)?

Thanks.

Comment: A document with embedded documents is really just one document. It's updated all at once. You might want to have a `Users` collection and an `Avatar` collection (or just documents in a single collection). A user document would contain the `_id` of the `Avatar`.

Comment: I'd recommend you read [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) page for some common modeling practices in MongoDB.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: I did go through the documentation (which is excellent btw), but I'm not sure what's the best practice for my example.  According to your first comment, my problems 1,2,3 don't exist, so the first option seems simple enough, it avoids the need for an _id in each embedded document.  Thanks for your kind advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the document inside a document model?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("515c99f7e4d8094a87e13758"),
    "active_avatar_id" : 2,
    "avatars" : {
        "1" : {
            "url" : "http://example.com/img/photo1.jpg",
            "width" : 50,
            "height" : 50
        },
        "2" : {
            "url" : "http://example.com/img/photo2.jpg",
            "width" : 50,
            "height" : 50
        }
    }
}
```